# How to use an image as a number?

Tags: front-end, formatting, curated-data, conversion

How to define an image as a number?

for instance I want to do something like this

[image]

where

[image]

but there is an error massage

[image]

```
Ten = WolframAlpha["10 of spades", {{"Image", 1}, "Content"},
InputAssumptions -> {"*MC.%7E-_*CardRank-"}]
```

[image]

and

```
Ace = WolframAlpha["Ace of hearts", {{"Image", 1}, "Content"}, 
InputAssumptions -> {"*MC.%7E-_*CardRank-"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sure there are better ways, but I guess you could go with upvalues. Define a wrapper e.g. `card` and do something like:
`card /; Plus[card[x],card[y]] := CardRank[x] + CardRank[y]`.

Comment: @AndreasP it should be `/:` :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To minimize confusion I've reduced the code to one approach.

```
ClearAll[Ten, Ace];

getImage = WolframAlpha[
   #, {{"Image", 1}, "Content"}, InputAssumptions -> {"*MC.%7E-_*CardRank-"}
] &;

With[{  pic = ToBoxes@getImage[#]  }, 
    #2 /: MakeBoxes[#2, fmt_] := InterpretationBox[pic, #3]
] & @@@ {
  {"10 of spades", Ten, 10}, 
  {"Ace of hearts", Ace, 11}
}
```

```
Defer[Ten + Ace/Ten]
```

[image]